# Is it correct to say "Practice these words."?

Tags: nouns, gerunds

I usually say "Practice pronouncing these words correctly." Is it correct to say "Practice these words."?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can say *Practice these words* if the understanding is that by *practice* you mean *practice pronouncing*, *practice writing*, etc *these words*. So, *practice these words* is implicit for saying something more explicit. It's fine and natural.

Comment: While I'd not disagree, answers on ELU need supporting evidence from a recognised authority. Can you find one without having to pinch @Glorfindel's?